# How do you change the Delphi DBDEMOS Alias so it points to the public data folder?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm running Delphi XE4 on a Windows 7 machine.

I've determined that the DBDEMOS alias points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Borland Shared\Data.

How can I configure Delphi XE4 so the DBDEMOS alias points to C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\11.0\Samples\Data?

Comment: I think you can use dbexplor.exe, but previously there was bdeadmin.exe, I think...

Comment: Yes you can. Make that an answer and I'll vote it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'dbexplor.exe' that resides in the 'bin' folder of RAD Studio installation (which is either "Database Explorer" or "SQL Explorer" [(depending on version (?)) which either can edit BDE aliases](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tools_for_Working_with_the_BDE)).